# Guideline 2.1 - Performance - blank unresponsive screen

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, ios14

I have tried my app on all possible simulators and real devices. It works fine but I keep getting rejected for the same reason. Here is what I got:

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 14.0 on Wi-Fi.

Your app launches to a blank unresponsive screen and does not load any content after repeated attempts.

Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try on `iOS 14`?

Comment: Assuming it's an iPhone app: did you try running it on an iPad?

Comment: @pgb Yes! I tries it on iPad, iPhone, and iPod using iOS 14 and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Rob Yes! I tried it on iOS 14.

Comment: @AnoushaFarshid Ok, did your app already existed on App Store?

Comment: @Rob No! Actually this is my first app.